# Android detect app launch

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, launch

Hi I'm trying to develop an app that detect app launch, many app like app lock, smart app lock e.g

1-user clicks on "contact" app (for example)

2-my app detects launch of an app

3-my app confirms it is the "contact" app

4- my app opens a view over the top, asking for a password

5-user enters a password, if correct, my app disappears, leaving the "contact" app on top

i am see lot of answers that advise to read log but READ_LOGS permission is not work with jelly bean.
Can any body help me? i don't understand how it possible?
Any pointers would help. thanks for any help

Comment: is going to be for a set of specific apps? or will the apps to check be user defined?

Comment: READ_LOGS permission is work, but since API level 16 reading logs from other apps has been disabled, you can read your app logs only. Does anyone know how AppLockers overcame this hurdle?

Comment: @Plo_Koon have u found any solution ?

Comment: @Plo_Koon did you find a solution? how is app locker able to do it ?